# Codeigniter update_batch - Undefined index: id

Tags: php, codeigniter

i had recently gotten help updating multiple data in the database using codeigniter. but on running the code i got Message:  **Undefined index: id**

**Controller**

```php
public function update_record()
{
    $id = ["19821", "19923", "19966", "19967"];
    $total = ["8", "118", "90", "100"];
    $update_data = [];
    foreach ($id as $key => $value) {
        $update_data[] = [
            'id'    => $value,
            'total' => $total[$key]
        ];
    }

    if ($this->some_model->batch_data('records', $update_data) == true) {
        echo "yes";
    } else {
        echo "no";
    }

}
```

**Model**

```php
public function batch_data($table, $data)
{
    $this->db->update_batch($table, $data, 'id'); // this will set the id column as the condition field
    return true;
}
```

**Running this i got:**

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: id</p>
<p>Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1949</p>
```

Comment: Do you know what CI version you are using? there are [open issue](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4892) on CI github regarding the `update_batch` method started from v3.1.1 to v3.1.2

Comment: @Hasta Dhana  am using v3.1.2

Comment: that is exactly the version that has this bug, maybe you could upgrade it

Comment: @HastaDhana I just updated my version of codeigniter and everything works just fine. thanks

Comment: glad I could help :)